# Media Queries in Material-UI Using Styled-Components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Material UI has a nice set of built-in media queries:  https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#css-media-queries

Material UI also allows us to use Styled-Components with Material UI:  https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#styled-components

I want to know how to combine the two together.  That is, how can I make media queries using Styled Components and Material-UI's built-in breakpoints?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'


import {
  AppBar as MuiAppBar,
  Drawer as MuiDrawer,
  Toolbar,
} from '@material-ui/core'


const drawerWidth = 240

const AdminLayout = ({ children }) => {

  return (
    <BaseLayout>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          TOOLBAR
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer>
        DRAWER
      </Drawer>
      {children}
    </BaseLayout>
  )
}

AdminLayout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default AdminLayout

// ------- STYLES -------
const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar)`
  /* Implement appBar styles from useStyles */
`

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer)`
  /* Implement drawer styles from useStyles */
`

// STYLES THAT I WANT TO CONVERT TO STYLED-COMPONENTS
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  drawer: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
    },
  },
  appBar: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
      marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    },
  },
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
}))
```

Comment: `theme.breakpoints.down('sm')` is just a string `'(min-width:600px)'`, use it in the styled-component

Comment: That requires me hard-coding the pixel value -- what if I want to use the `sm` variable?

Comment: what? you don't hardcoding when you using `theme.breakpoints.down('sm')`

Comment: perhaps I'm not following.  Would you mind showing me an example of how to use `theme.breakpoints.down('sm')` in a styled-component?

Comment: Make a minimal example of what you trying to style with MU without styled-components and I'll show you an example on it

Comment: Also, why you need this overhead when you have the default values listed https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#javascript-media-queries (there are only few of them)

Comment: I have updated the question to show what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Below is an example showing one way of leveraging the Material-UI theme breakpoints with styled-components. This is passing the Material-UI theme to the styled-components `ThemeProvider` in order to make it available as a prop within the styles. The example also uses `StylesProvider` with the `injectFirst` prop so that the Material-UI styles will occur at the beginning of the `<head>` rather than the end, so that the styled-components styles occur after the Material-UI styles and therefore win when specificity is otherwise equal.

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { ThemeProvider as SCThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { useTheme, StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MuiAppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar)`
  background-color: red;
  ${props => props.theme.breakpoints.up("sm")} {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  ${props => props.theme.breakpoints.up("md")} {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
  }
  ${props => props.theme.breakpoints.up("lg")} {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
  }
`;
export default function App() {
  const muiTheme = useTheme();
  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <SCThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
        <AppBar>Sample AppBar</AppBar>
      </SCThemeProvider>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit MUI theme breakpoints with styled-components]

Related documentation:

- styled-components theme usage: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming
- StylesProvider injectFirst: https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#stylesprovider

Comment: Something like this worked for me: 
const GridBox = styled(Box)`
  ${({theme}) => `
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    ${theme.breakpoints.up("sm")} {
      grid-template-columns: 5fr 3fr;
    };
  `}
`;

Comment: In my opinion this has too much emotion flavor. I prefer the solution by Mike Mathew that does not use emotion syntax.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using the ["Style Objects" approach](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#style-objects) (i.e., "JavaScript") to styled-components, then this is the way to achieve that same outcome. This builds on top of what Ryan Cogswell mentioned earlier.

Some might prefer this if switching over from another CSS-in-JS system (like Material-UI's built-in JSS). Also, the "Style Objects" approach only requires you to bring in `props` one time as opposed to using the `props` variable on any line. It's good to have choices.

#### Style Object

```
const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar)((props) => ({
  backgroundColor: red;

  [props.theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    backgroundColor: orange,
  },
  [props.theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
    backgroundColor: yellow,
    color: black,
  },
  [props.theme.breakpoints.up("lg")]: {
    backgroundColor: green,
    color: white,
  },
}));
```

#### Style Object, but more concise

Since we only need to access the props one time using the JavaScript approach and we only use theme in this style area, we can destructure `theme` from the incoming `props` for a bit less code.

```js
const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: red;

  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    backgroundColor: orange,
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
    backgroundColor: yellow,
    color: black,
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.up("lg")]: {
    backgroundColor: green,
    color: white,
  },
}));
```

Note: If you are using TypeScript and have set up your styled-components theme to match the Material-UI theme, then type safety still works as expected in either the  CSS or JavaScript approach.

Answer (score 0):

The [breakpoints are provided](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#css-media-queries) as part of the default theme.

They are constants and won't change, therefore you can use them across the components or styled themes:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
  console.log('md', theme.breakpoints.up('md'));
  return {};
});

const BP = {
  MD: `@media (min-width:960px) `,
};

const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: green;

  ${({ bp }) => bp} {
    background-color: red;
  }
`;

export default function StyledComponentsButton() {
  useStyles();
  return <Container bp={BP.MD}>Example</Container>;
}
```

[image: Edit Styled Components]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and all the time you have put into this.  I'm sorry to say, though, but this is not what I am trying to do.  For starters, `const BP` hard-codes the pixel value for the `md` breakpoint.  But I want to use the `md` breakpoint that is found in `theme.breakpoints`.  Secondly, I don't want to have rely on a prop -- I just want to insert the media query into the Styled Component.

Comment: My question is how do I access theme.breakpoint inside a styled-component.

Comment: Pass it with styled-themes as I mentioned couple of times

Answer (score 0):

The syntax may look weird, but trying this code will explain everything

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  ${({theme}) => {
  console.log(theme.breakpoints.up('lg'));
  return "";
}}
`;
// you will see in your console
// @media (min-width:1280px)
```

Once you understand that `theme.breakpoints.up('lg')` is same as `@media (min-width:1280px)` everything become obvious. everytime you put `theme.breakpoints.up(key)` it get replaced with `@media...` string.

Answer (score -3):

```
const StyledDrawer = styled(Drawer)(
  ({ theme }) => `
  .MuiDrawer-paper {
    ${theme.breakpoints.up('sm')} {
      width: 370px;
    }

    ${theme.breakpoints.down('sm')} {
      width: 100vw;
    }
  }   
`)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.