# Override material-ui button styles with styled-components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am using a `material-ui button` and trying to override the border-radius (i.e, make it 0) through styled-components. However, it's not working.

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: #d29d12;
  border-radius: 0;
`;

export default function App() {
  return <StyledButton>Hello</StyledButton>;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

By default, Material-UI injects it styles at the end of the `<head>` element. This means that its styles will come **after** styles generated by styled-components and thus the Material-UI styles will win over the styled-components styles when [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is the same.

You can use the `StylesProvider` component with the `injectFirst` property to move the Material-UI styles to the beginning of the `<head>` and then the styled-components styles will come after it and win.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <div className="App">
        <StyledButton>Hello</StyledButton>
      </div>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit styled-components]

Related answers:

- [Media Queries in Material-UI Using Styled-Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921880/media-queries-in-material-ui-using-styled-components/59922445#59922445)

Comment: I think this is actually the right answer based on ops question and Material UI Docs.

Comment: Using `injectFirst` move the styles to the beginning of `head` but also results in pushing the `meta` tags below them and W3C validator issues some errors regarding "charset attribute on a meta element found after the first 1024 bytes". Any ideas?

Comment: @n4m31ess_c0d3r The documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#insertionpoint) provides details on how to control the exact insertion point.

Answer (score 7):

Use styled-components higher specificity syntax:
https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  && {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const StyledButton = styled(Button)({
  '&&&': {
    backgroundColor: red,
    borderRadius: 0
  }
)}
```

Comment: for some reason, this doesn't work with css interpolation

Answer (score 1):

By adding className to StyledButton, it can override MUI button style,

```
<StyledButton className={'myclassName'}>Hello</styledButton>

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
 &.myclassName {
    background-color: red,
    border-radius: 0
  }
`;
```

Answer (score -5):

You can override the default border-radius of button by applying !important to your styled component.

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  borderRadius: 0px !important;
`;
```