# 'Undefined' when attempting to pass MaterialUI theme props to styled components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I'm attempting to access my Material-UI theme props within a styled component, however I keep getting...

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'primary' of undefined` or similar errors in the browser.

Here is my custom theme (`index.ts`)

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core";
import { blue } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: blue[800],
        contrastText: "#FFF"
      },
      secondary: {
        main: blue[600],
        contrastText: "#FFF"
      }
    },
    typography : {
        fontFamily: [
            "Nunito",
            "Roboto",
        ].join(",") 
    }
});

export default theme;
```

Here is where my theme wraps my application in the `App.tsx`

```
// Other imports
import theme from "../../app/theme/index";

const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <StylesProvider injectFirst>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    // Routing stuff
                </ThemeProvider>
            </StylesProvider>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

And here is where I am attempting to use my styled component

```
import { ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Brand = styled(ListItem)`
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.palette.primary.dark},
    padding: ${props => props.theme.spacing(1)},
    font-size: ${props => props.theme.typography.h6.fontSize},
    font-weight: ${props => props.theme.typography.fontWeightMedium},
    color: "white",
    min-height: "64px",
    padding-left: ${props => props.theme.spacing(6)}
`;

const SidebarNew: React.FC = () => {

    return (
        <Brand button>
            // Stuff
        </Brand>
    );
};

export default SidebarNew;
```

This compiles but fails in the browser. What am I missing here?

If I use material-ui's built in `styled` like below, it appears to work, however I would prefer to use `styled-components` directly

```
const Brand = styled(ListItem)(({ theme }) => ({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    fontSize: theme.typography.h6.fontSize,
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
    color: "white",
    minHeight: 64,
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(6)
}));
```

Comment: You need to use the `styled-components` `ThemeProvider` in addition to the Material-UI `ThemeProvider`. You can specify the same theme in both providers. For an example of using the `styled-components` `ThemeProvider`, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921880/media-queries-in-material-ui-using-styled-components/59922445#59922445.

Comment: I still can't get this to work with an example based on the answer to your linked question - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-theme-bhy1h. Where might I still be going wrong? Could it be TypeScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `ThemeProvider` from styled-components (`SCThemeProvider` in the example below) in addition to the Material-UI `ThemeProvider`; otherwise styled-components won't know about your theme.

Here is a working example:

```
import {
  createMuiTheme,
  StylesProvider,
  ThemeProvider
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { ThemeProvider as SCThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import * as React from "react";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import "./styles.css";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#1a1aff",
      contrastText: "#FFF"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#ff3333",
      contrastText: "#FFF"
    }
  },
  typography: {
    h5: {
      fontSize: "10px"
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <SCThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Dashboard />
        </SCThemeProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material-UI Theme (forked)]